# Does neo4jphp(or REST) support search queries with both white spaces and wildcards

Tags: php, rest, lucene, neo4j, neo4jphp

Does neo4jphp(REST)(indexing on Lucene), support search queries with both white spaces and wildcards.

Actually I am running the following query:

`$testindex->query(name:"jim grand udu*"); //here lucene indexes neo4j nodes by property "name"`

but it does not match anything, even if exact matches are available. It seems the * here loses its power and is just passed as a string. If i use it with a single word term it works.

`$testindex->query(name:jim*); //This Works`

It seems * loses its meaning inside quotes but white spaces dont work unless i use quotes - So seems they cant be used together. Any help would be appreciated, i cant find the solution in the documentation of neo4jphp or neo4j's REST, I know this is possible in lucene and neo4j javaapi using wildcardquery. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the queries from a command line curl call, or through the Neo4j web admin inteface?

Comment: Hi Josh, This works for space queries http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/actors?query=name:%22jim%20grand%20udupa%22 This works for star queries: http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/actors?query=name:jim*  But this is not working for both star and space: http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/actors?query=name:%22jim%20grand%20udu*%22 . I am not sure how to make this work.

Comment: This also works: http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/actors?query=name:%22jim%20grand%22%20AND%20name:udu%2A But * doesnt seem to work within quotes in REST itself. Or can it be made to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it works for me on Neo4j - 2.0.0-M06)

```
GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/node_auto_index?query=name:Ke*nu~%20AND%20name:R*ves~
```

i.e. name:[first_string] AND name:[second_string].....

Search for Apache Lucene - Query Parser Syntax for more details.